# what is the benefit of using multiple modules in Angular2 apart from simplicity in designing?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-module, angular2-modules

Will it help to reduce the loading time?(like by loading only current module to client's device? )

what I understand is that...

- It will increase the number of request between server and client?
- It will increase the complexity of your code.(Since you need to take
  care of
- importing and exporting modules and take special care in routing too)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Angular supports lazy loading of modules. This way you can split up your application into parts that are loaded only on demand.

```
{
  path: 'admin',
  loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
},
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#asynchronous-routing

**update**

While lazy loading doesn't reduce the load time when everything is required at the start page which is IMHO not the case in almost 100% of Angular2 applications, it reduces the time for the initial load and delays the load time to when a module is actually required.
Angular also supports preload feature to load lazy loaded modules before they are required, but still doesn't load them with the initial load.

- > It will increase the number of request between server and client?

The number of requests will be higher, but the amount of data loaded with the first request will be less. The main idea is to reduce the time until the user gets the first screen rendered. If an applications consists of parts where some are heavily used and other rarely, then it's usually a good idea to not load the rarely used parts until they are actually used - which means "lazy" or "on demand" - only when actually required.

- > It will increase the complexity of your code.(Since you need to take care of

If you want to gain full benefit of lazy loading, you will need to think about your architecture. That doesn't mean the code needs to become more complex. You just need to make decisions which module you put your components, directives, services into.

- > importing and exporting modules and take special care in routing too)

I don't see much difference here, because you should split your application in different modules (for example per feature) anyway, even if they are not lazy loaded.

Comment: That's true. But in real world business line applications this angular feature doesn't contribute very much to loading performance (beside the starter screen), as a typical modul with application components typically references almost the full stack of application features (dataservices, ...). Angular should support lazy-loading on a finer granularity level in the future.

Comment: @Karl no idea what you mean. You can make the modules as fine granular as you want (single component, directive, or service)

Comment: @Günther: I suppose a directive (in a referenced module) is loaded when the component triggered by "loadChildren is loaded?

Comment: Sure, but why would it be referenced when it's not used. If it's used it needs to be loaded, no?

Comment: That's what I meant, they are "needed" by design and therefore loaded. e.g. in a typical CRUD application (insert, delete, ...) are part of the design, but you never know if a user triggers all functions. they are all loaded, but maybe never used. Right now, you can't control wether they are loaded or not except each feature is linked to a route, which is not practical

Comment: No idea why you think "they are all loaded". They are loaded if a module is loaded that references them.

Comment: Ty @GünterZöchbauer for your answer. So basically It'll load all components of rootModule initially and will call the childModule only when it is needed, right?.

Comment: @Karl my question was Angular2 specific and I think you're talking about Angular 1. (PS: Sorry If I'm wrong as I'm new to this Angular world. ':) )

Comment: @YASHDAVE with the initial load the `AppModule` and all modules listed in `imports: [...] are loaded`. When the user navigates to a route that uses `loadChildren` to lazy load a module, then this module and all modules listed in `imports: [...]` of this module (which weren't already loaded previously) are loaded. You can use the `preLoad` feature, then lazy loaded modules are loaded in the background after the initial load to be available when the user navigates to such a route.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer So Lazy loading is useful only for larger applications which has atleast 2 levels in module tree.(By that way children of child modules will be loaded only when its parent module is called by client, right?) Thanks for all the efforts for solving my queries and also thanks for that asynchronous-routing link. It solved almost my all queries.

Comment: I'd say the larger the application, the more likely it is that lazy loading will bring benefits - as mentioned it also depends on application structure and usage patterns. You need to be able to split your application so that one part is loaded immediately and one or more other parts are loaded on demand, where "part" is a set of modules. A good example is an Admin module that is normally not used by most users, only when an administrator logs in the route to navigate to that module is show at all and therefore only be usable by admins.

Comment: Why should still all users need to wait to get this module downloaded, when they are not even allowed to use it.

Comment: @YASHDAVE: I was referring to Angular 2. Günther is adressing my issue in the update to his answer. A typical business application has a foundation layer used by other business components. In Angular you can shift loading this layer from the starter screen to the (first loaded) business component. You can't control  the loading of single modules, components, ... within this  business component

Comment: ohh sorry @Karl I misread your 1st comment,thx for help.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think its angular specific question. There are tons of answers why you should use modules if you google for them, for example have a look here: [modules](http://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html)

Now short answers to your question:

- it will not help to reduce the loading time
- it will increase the number of requests
- it will actually help to decrease the complexity of the code by decoupling non-related functionality and not having to pollute global namespaces

Comment: Of course it will reduce the loading time. If the start page doesn't display parts of your application which is the case in 99,9% of the applications, the it reduces the initial load time.

Comment: Lets be precise here - in the question author has not specified 'initial load time'. If we are speaking about 'loading time' for application in general - it will not be reduced and (at least as for now) it most likely will be increased.

Comment: That might be, but that might be a mistake in the question and definitely is a mistake in your answer. If several modules are not loaded because the user never navigated to these routes, then the load time will definitely be way shorter. Only when all or almost all modules are actually used the load times will sum up to the load time (or more) you get without lazy loading.

Comment: As long as the question is stated the way it is - I do not see my answer as being wrong. But in any case I think the author will benefit from knowing the differences.

Comment: And as a minor side point. If we are speaking about large applications that are build up of hundreds of modules, many of those are loaded at once (lets say this is dashboard style main page with lots of addins) at start up, and what is important the application itself operates in a 2G network with big latency and hundreds of concurrent clients at a time. Such cases are common in enterprise environments and there - loading time might unfortunately degrade to unacceptable levels.

Comment: "It might" but "it will not help to reduce the loading time" is an unconditional statement that just is not true.

Comment: It actually will help to reduce the loading time by eliminating latencies of hundreds small requests.

Comment: That just sounds like the granularity of the modules isn't a good fit for the application you are talking about. This sounds like you are loading every module lazy, which doesn't make sense of course. Normally it's bound with routing, when a user changes to a route the first time one module with all its dependencies is loaded at once. Only if the user does hundreds of navigations, hundreds of small requests are made if every such route is implemented by a lazy loaded module.

Comment: I think we have got out of topic by delving into specific use cases that are a matter of development/architect decisions that are too broad to discuss here.

Comment: Lazy loading **is** about architecture. I doesn't make sense to me to talk about lazy loading and excluding the architecture topic. But I think I got my point across and agree that we can end the discussion.